# $\mathbb{Z}_p$ not isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_p|[t]|$

Tags: ring-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $\mathbb{Z}_p$ the ring of $p$-adic numbers and $\mathbb{F}_p|[t]|= \{ \sum_j ^{\infty} a_j t^j \}$ and the ring of formal power series.

I don't see how to show that $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and $\mathbb{F}_p|[t]|$ aren't isomorphic as rings.

Comment: A ring isomorphism preserves characteristic.

Comment: Contrary to what the notation suggests, $\mathbb{Z}_p$ contains a subring isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @Max: Some paths through algebra give one the expectation that $\mathbb{Z}_{\mathrm{subscript}}$ is some sort of extension of $\mathbb{Z}$, such as a localization or a completion; containing $\mathbb{Z}$ is very much what the notation does suggest! The use of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for the finite field really irritates me since $\mathbb{F}_p$ is even better (it generalizes to any finite field, not just of prime order), and if its use were more common we wouldn't have this conflict of conventions.

Comment: While elements of $\Bbb Z_p$ might be represented as infinite sums $\sum_{n \geq 0} a_n p^n$ with $0 \leq a_n < p$, it is very different from $\Bbb F_p[[t]]$. For instance $\underbrace{1 \cdot p^0 + \cdots + 1 \cdot p^0}_{p \text{ times}} = 1 \cdot p^1$ in $\Bbb Z_p$, while $\underbrace{1 \cdot t^0 + \cdots + 1 \cdot t^0}_{p \text{ times}} = 0 \in \Bbb F_p[[t]]$.

Comment: @Hurkyl : of course, but often when one begins in algebra, things with a subscript $p$ are of characteristic $p$.. but actually my comment was also half-ironic, precisely because of what you're saying

Comment: Possibly related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2436717

Comment: Somehow, in $\Bbb Z_p$, there is a "carry" (looking in terms of the sums $\sum_n a_n p^n$ as above), which does not happen for $\Bbb F_p[[t]]$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\renewcommand{\power}{[\![t]\!]}$
Assume that $\phi : \Bbb F_p\power \to \Bbb Z_p$ is a ring morphism (it might not even be an isomorphism). Then $$p = p \cdot 1_{\Bbb Z_p} = p \cdot \phi(1_{\Bbb F_p})
= \phi(p \cdot 1_{\Bbb F_p}) = \phi(0) = 0,$$
which is not possible. Indeed,
the ring $\Bbb Z_p$ has characteristic $0$ (even if it is an inverse limit of rings of positive characteristic [which actually grows to infinity, that's why the inverse limit has characteristic $0$, somehow]). Said differently, $\Bbb Z_p$ contains a copy of $\Bbb Z$, via the injective ring morphism
$$
\begin{array}{lrcl}
 & \Bbb Z & \longrightarrow &  \Bbb Z_p \hookrightarrow \prod\limits_{m \geq 0} \Bbb Z /p^m \Bbb Z \\
    & n & \longmapsto & ([n]_{p^m})_{m \geq 0}.
\end{array}
$$

---

Some remarks:

– Actually, $\Bbb F_p\power$ is not even isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_p$ as additive group, since $\Bbb Z_p$ is torsion-free.

– However, we have a [ring isomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53552) $\Bbb Z_p \cong \Bbb Z\power / (t - p)$.

Comment: Actually, $( \Bbb F_p[[t]], +)$ is a group of finite exponent (namely $p$), so the only group morphism $( \Bbb F_p[[t]], +) \to (\Bbb Z_p, +)$ is the zero morphism, since $\Bbb Z_p$ is torsion-free. So there are no unital ring morphism $\Bbb F_p[[t]] \to \Bbb Z_p$.

Comment: (Recall that the additive group of an integral domain of characteristic $0$ is torsion-free).